# Node.JS and Socket.io - Broadcast returns to sender

Tags: node.js, socket.io, broadcast

I am building a real-time web-application with multiple clients and a node.js server to handle state and broadcast event changes from clients. I have implemented Socket.io as transport mechanism between clients and server. When a client performs a specific action an event this is send to the server, which is broadcasted to other clients on the network.

However, *sometimes* when an array of events is recieved by the server, the server doesn't broadcast it but instead sends it back to the sending client - or sends it to all connected sockets including the sending client.

Here is a snippet of the server implementation, which basically listens for client events, collects them in an array which is broadcasted every 2 seconds.

If you want, I can include relevant snippets from the client implementation.

```
// Require HTTP module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var http = require('http'), io = require('socket.io'), users = require('./users');

// Commands to client
var USER_LOGIN = 0,
    USER_LIST = 1,
    USER_CONNECTED = 2,
    USER_DISCONNECTED = 3,
    COMMAND = 4,
    COMMAND_SETNICKNAME = 0,
    COMMAND_POSITION = 1,
    COMMAND_MOUSEDOWN = 2,

var array = [];
var activeUsers = {};


// Start the server at port 8080
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
    res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
});
server.listen(8080);

// Create a Socket.IO instance, passing it our server
var io = io.listen(server);

// Add a connect listener
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){ 
    console.log("started");


    // Create periodical which ends a JSON message to the client every 2 seconds
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(array.length >0) {
            console.log("Sending to clients " + array);
        //client.send(JSON.stringify(array));
        client.broadcast.send(JSON.stringify(array));
        array = [];
    }
},2000);

// Success!  Now listen to messages to be received
client.on('message',function(event){ 
        console.log("--Reading event " + event);
        var eventArray = JSON.parse(event);
    for(var i = 0; i < eventArray.length; i++) {
        var dataArray = eventArray[i];
        var userId = parseInt(dataArray[0]);
        var position = 1;

        console.log("current element in array " + dataArray);

        switch (parseInt(dataArray[position++])) {
            case USER_LOGIN: 
                // Log in user with USERID. 
                var username = dataArray[position++];
                console.log("Attempting to log in with user " + username);

                // If valid, send USER_LOGIN broadcast to clients
                if(login(username)) {
                    array.push([0, USER_LOGIN, login(username)]);
                }
                break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){ 
    console.log("started");


    // Create periodical which ends a JSON message to the client every 2 seconds
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(array.length >0) {
            console.log("Sending to clients " + array);
        //client.send(JSON.stringify(array));
        client.broadcast.send(JSON.stringify(array));
        array = [];
    }
},2000);
```

you are creating one scheduler for each connection which is going to be a mess. Because you are creating the interval inside `on('connection',`
And I don't see any point of calling clients in an interval because you have a method to push the changes on some clients change event. That is the advantage of socket.io . Instead of using an interval you can just broadcast the change in another listener from client change event like this.

```
client.on('onSomechangeInClient',function(event){ 
  //update array here..
 client.broadcast.send(JSON.stringify(array));
});
```

Comment: Thank you - I see your point on just broadcasting changes whenever they come instead of using a scheduler.